# How can I set cookies using Picasso for Android?

Tags: java, android, picasso

I've tried to set cookies to be sent when requesting for images using Picasso but it doesn't seem to send any cookies by monitoring the network for HTTP headers.

I've built a Picasso instance as follows and tried to use HttpURLConnection for downloader and set cookies using cookieSyncManager.

What could I be doing wrong?

```
Builder picassoBuilder = new Picasso.Builder(this);
Downloader downloader = new UrlConnectionDownloader(this);
picassoBuilder.downloader(downloader);

Picasso picasso = picassoBuilder.build();

CookieSyncManager cookieSyncManager = CookieSyncManager.createInstance(this);
CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();

cookieManager.setCookie("http://example.com/", "key=value");
cookieSyncManager.sync();

picasso.with(this).load("http://example.com/image.php?image=test.png").into(imageView);
```

Comment: You spelled `example.com` wrong in the setCookie method

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo when typing in here. Fixed.

Comment: `Picasso` does not know about your `CookieManager`, I guess you have to subclass `UrlConnectionDownloader` & modify the url connection. `CookieSyncManager` is for cookies within a `WebView`, not those that may or may not be used with `HttpUrlConnection`

Comment: have you managed to setup a request with cookies using picasso?

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to do this using OkHttp and OkHttp3Downloader.
You need to use an Interceptor and then set cookies in the request ([ref](https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/1259)). Also, you need to set cache manually, because (in some cases) doesn't work when you use a custom downloader ([ref](https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/1185))

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient()
    .newBuilder()
    .addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
        @Override
        public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
            final Request original = chain.request();

            final Request authorized = original.newBuilder()
                    .addHeader("Cookie", CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(yourUrl))
                    .addHeader("User-Agent", yourUserAgent)
                    .build();

            return chain.proceed(authorized);
        }
    })
    .cache(new Cache(context.getCacheDir(), 25 * 1024 * 1024))
    .build();



Picasso picasso = new Picasso.Builder(context)
                  .downloader(new OkHttp3Downloader(client))
                  .memoryCache(new LruCache(context))
                  .build();

picasso.load(yourUrlImage).into(yourView);
```

Dependency

```
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.8.1'
compile 'com.jakewharton.picasso:picasso2-okhttp3-downloader:1.1.0'
```